# How to prevent select and copy on select element

Tags: javascript

I have a select element which gets populated with data from database. This select element is hidden.

What I want is to disable copying of the content of this Select. The only way a user may do copying now is by using Ctrl+A or  from menu or by View Source. How to prevent this?

(Note: I do not want the entire page to be freezed. No solution like document.onselectstart= return false kind of. Only the select element contents should not get copied.)

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: No matters what you do with document.onselectstart (anyway if the element is hidden it won't be selected) you can't prevent the user to see and copy that code from "View source" or something like that.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent that?

Comment: you can try to lockdown your page with as much javascript as you want, doesn't mean the user can't just view source or just turn the javascript off with a plugin like [noscript](http://noscript.net/)

Comment: One cosmetic solution could be to make the selected text's color and its background color the same as the non selected one... worth just as much as other tricks.

Comment: Store the data in server side memory only. (e.g. Session in .NET)

Comment: And if you could, Why do you want it? DONT TOUCH THE USER EXPECTED BEHAVOIR!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Restructure your application instead. Do not send sensitive or secret data as part of the HTML.

Comment: Thanks Deestan for being affirmative. I will have to try restructuring. But any chance of using encrypting the content which is practically workable also ?

Comment: Yes, encrypting will work if it is decrypted again on the server side.  If it is being decrypted by client side JavaScript, it does not work. Cookies are a better storage for such things than HTML, though.

Comment: Thanks much Deestan. I am closing this.

Comment: Mr Deestan, I had an afterthought on this. What if I write an applet and provide few methods to access the relevant data alone. In that case they do not get to copy the whole data. Any other issue with this ? Thought to check an expert opinion before going ahead.

Comment: You would in essence be facing the same issue with the applet.  Data contained in or processed by the applet is accessible to the end user just like the HTML data is. -- Though it will be somewhat more obfuscated, so this all depends on the sensitivity of your data.